# iOS11 AppIcon can't change

Tags: ios, ios11

- Xcode 9 beta 6
- iOS 11 beta 10

  I want package application with custom App icon , so I try to replace AppIcon.png files at DerivedData (/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.app)

  It worked at iOS 10, but doesn't work at iOS 11

  Can anybody solve it?

  Thanks for advance

Comment: why in derived data? Don't you have the code? If you don't have then change in IPA file by creating it is a Zip file, add your new images and again convert a zip to IPA file. In last do code resign by any tool say Fastlane.

Comment: I have code , but I creat a new custom icon with buildversion by shell scrip, and I try to replace it, and failed at iOS 11

Comment: perfect you have code & icons as well. Now check where App icons are located in your code. Should be in imageassets folder. Open assets folder select App Icon & drag-drop your new icon files.

Comment: I did know how to change app icon through Images.xcassets, but I don't have new pic as icon, the pic generating by script when I build my application

Comment: @Paladinfeng, you may be aware of the compiler hashes the files during building the package (i.e. debug or release), therefore you cannot just replace a file in the bundle after that – your script must run before it, or you need to change to icon in the project before compilation.

Comment: @holex thanks, I guess the reason similar with you, Xcode 9 doesn't allow to do this, but I really want know what they do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution.
I change app icons in the source .xcasset folder, not in Derived Data (using ImageMagick). So, here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
BASE_ICONS_DIR=$(find ${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME} -name "AppIcon.appiconset")
IFS=$' '
CONTENTS_JSON="${BASE_ICONS_DIR}/Contents.json"

version=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"`
# The next line adds special suffix, necessary in my project
version="${version/'$(VERSION_SUFFIX)'/$VERSION_SUFFIX}"

function tag() {
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/
    ICON_PATH=$1

    width=`identify -format %w ${ICON_PATH}`
    [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit 1

    height=$((width * 30 / 100))

    if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" != "AppStore" ]; then
       convert -background '#0008' \
       -fill white -gravity center \
       -size ${width}x${height} \
       caption:"${version}" \
       "${ICON_PATH}" +swap -gravity south -composite "${ICON_PATH}" || exit 1
    fi
}

ICONS=(`grep 'filename' "${CONTENTS_JSON}" | cut -f2 -d: | tr -d ',' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '"'`)

ICONS_COUNT=${#ICONS[*]}

IFS=$'\n'

for (( i=0; i<ICONS_COUNT; i++ )); do
    tag "$BASE_ICONS_DIR/${ICONS[$i]}"
done
```

This script is executed before `Copy Bundle Resources`. After executing app icons are changed, so I need to revert changes with additional Run Script as a last Build Phase:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" != "AppStore" ]; then
   IFS=$'\n'
   git checkout -- `find "${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}" -name AppIcon.appiconset -type d`
fi
```

My Build Phases looks like this:

[image: My Build Phases looks like this]

Comment: Can't we change icons in an IPA and resigning it?